# Are there any web applications with user-driven multiprocessing tasks?

Tags: python, web-services, multiprocessing

I have a long-running python script that needs to be executed by an arbitrary number of users for an arbitrary number of files. Multiprocessing and scalability are essential.

Based on a post regarding the multiprocessing module, it appears that a user reloading or resubmitting may be a problem as well as the server dropping tasks that run too long.

Is a desktop interface the best option, or are there any examples of a similar web application?

Comment: Since it sounds like these are long running and controllable tasks (only using multiprocessing for concurrency support), I'd look at using a *separate* task queue program - separate from the web application itself that is.

Comment: Here are some quick googly-picks: http://www.fullstackpython.com/task-queues.html (*many* aggregate resources) , http://www.celeryproject.org/ , http://python-rq.org/ or for a DIY: https://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/02/11/a-celerylike-python-task-queue-in-55-lines-of-code/

Comment: @user2864740, I believe web2py's scheduler is a task queue that technically operates separately from the web application. That is, processes/workers are started from the command line. I understood, for instance, celery to be an equal alternative to the scheduler

Comment: Remember: if you find a solution/answer then .. answer yourself! No need to update the post unless it's to add clarification of the problem/context.

Answer (score 1):

Web2py's scheduler may be a solution for up to about 50 concurrent processes. For more processes, state-of-the-art async processing (e.g., Celery) should be necessary.